# can cmake and netbeans play nice?

Tags: c++, netbeans, cmake

I'm working on a big project, some might say awesome.

The project is being developed in c++ with cmake and netbeans. Everything is working fine except from the fact that every time I do updates to the project, add or remove source files, netbeans runs cmake and adds a new project to 'projects' list. This is somewhat annoying since i tend to do this alot.

Is there a smart way to make sure netbeans does not create new projects every time a sub directory is added?

Comment: I want to know what the awesome project is.

Comment: just out of curiosity, any reason why you guys chose netbeans over eclipse?

Comment: @hopia: I dont choose eclipse becaurse my experience with it is that its pretty unstable and that the actual interface seams slow... but thats just my personal opinion :-)

Comment: @hopia I've tested both, but I prefer NetBeans. More supported and extended by the community, with a high variety of plugins, more easier to manage, more... more NetBeans.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen the accepted answer is out-of-date, NetBeans now handles CMake gracefully, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8027379/710951).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Good news!

As of NetBeans 6.8, CMake is handled gracefully, just like any other `configure` script:

1. Make a new "C/C++ Application from existing sources".
2. Specify the directory of the project (where `CMakeLists.txt` resides).
3. In the "Select configuration mode", select "Automatic".

And NetBeans will run `cmake` to build the `Makefile` when it's necessary
(or when you click "Reconfigure project").

See the [original thread on the NetBeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic26390.html) for more info.

Comment: Note: cmake, of course, must be installed on **build host**.

Comment: As at Netbeans 8.2 on macos High Sierra I see 'No make files or configure script were found in folder xxxx" despite CMakeLists.txt in that folder.

Comment: @DaveDurbin I think I am seeing the same thing. Did you find a work around? Did you go through the custom settings

Answer (score 25):

CMake-bases projects work perfect with NetBeans.

### Variation to *jmendeth* answer:

1. Create a new **`C/C++ Project with Existing Sources`**
2. Set the projects path (= directory of main `CMakeLists.txt`)
3. At **`Select Configuration mode`** set **`Custom`**
4. Click **`Next`**
5. Select **`Run Configure Script in Subfolder`** (the default folder is `build`)
6. If you don't have further settings, click **`Next`** until you can click finish
7. Click **`Finish`**, Cmake will run and build your project

This way is a bit longer then the automatic one, however in practice it's just setting of two ticks.

The advantage and hence the reason for the additional expenses: CMake will now put all it's ***local cache files*** in a ***subfolder*** (`build`) and keep them separate at one place - not mixing them with your other project stuff.

This keeps a clean project structure, since those files are just for your project and created by each configure run.

And as an extra: If you have to delete the CMake cache manually - this happens sometimes - there's one single directory where everything is in.

### Side note:

Since *NetBeans 8.0* there's *syntax coloring* for all CMake files.

Comment: I did not know about possibility of choosing build directory, and that was annoying me. Great to know that I can customize this.

Comment: Yes, it's really great feature.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error : "failed to start cmake: No such file or directory"

I had to NetBeans -> Preferences -> C/C++ (Build Tools) -> set the CMake Command to /opt/local/bin/cmake .

Answer (score 4):

I am using Cmake, netbeans and SVN with a large c++ project, with no problem.

I usually configure the project with the option "c++ with existing sources" and select
the makefile genereted by cmake so netbeans don't know which make tool I am using. Then select only the folders with the sources you need to work on.

Every time you update the sources you must update your Makefile (and the Netbeans Project will update the sources too) running cmake so you can do it manually or just in the build command of the project:  "cmake .. && make" (thats tricky but it works fine).
Hope to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the `cmake .. && make` idea.  I will note that to make it work in conjunction with NetBeans' remote build facility, I had to set the build command to something like `sh -c "cmake .. && make"`, to avoid having the remote shell execute the whole thing as a single command.