# How to configure a NetBeans/C++ project for different systems?

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, configuration, porting

In NetBeans/C++ I have a project that needs to be built on two different versions of Linux. 
Each of them has libraries in different paths, different versions of GCC, different versions of static and shared libraries, ...

One of the problems I have: the program links to `libmysqlclient.so`, on one system it builds without problems (linking to `libmysqlclient.so.16`), while on the other I get a run time error related to the missing library (while both `libmysqlclient.so.15` and `libmysqlclient.so.18` are available, and the paths are set correctly). And I did not specify the lib version number.

Is it possible to configure a project to be built on multiple systems?
Should I have to create multiple projects (sharing everything else, e.g. source code)?
Is there a quicker way?

Thank you.

---

NetBeans IDE 7.2 (C++)
Linux OpenSuse 11.4 / 10.2

Comment: You could learn to use `autotools` like `autoconf` etc.... Maybe `pkg-config` could also be relevant.

Comment: "while on the other I get a run time error related" what exactly is the error?

Answer (score 1):

I personally enjoy CMake every day I work with. We have a relatively complex project where subprojects are built on different platforms (Linux/Windows/Linux embedded) and where different developers prefer different IDEs. And everything works well with CMake. So I am sure that what you describe is pretty simple to get working with CMake, too.

See [can cmake and netbeans play nice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608569/can-cmake-and-netbeans-play-nice) for more information.

Comment: Your answer does not strictly cover my question, but I am going to rewrite the project from scratch with cmake.