# Netbeans project imported from existing cmake application fails to build with filesystem error on Windows

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, cmake, netbeans-8

I am attempting to import a manually-created cmake project that I had been using in a different IDE into Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows 7. Needless to say, my cmake configuration worked fine there.

Netbeans seems to import the directory fine. I imported it in "automatic" (cmake) mode. However, when I attempt to build the project, I get a rather cryptic (Java?) error message:

```
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /C/MinGW/bin/make.exe -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Knowing very little about Java, I am not sure how to interpret this error. The first directory (/C/MinGW/bin/make.exe) stands out to me as not being in Windows-format, but I am not sure if that's incorrect. I do indeed have a file by that name, as I copied the longer-named mingw make binary so I would only need to type "make".

Presuming this is being run in the project root, and that the first directory is formatted correctly, I don't see any problem with finding these files.

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

set(Project_Name "Test")
set(Test_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(Test_VERSION_MINOR 0)

project(${Project_Name})

include_directories(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/SDL"
    "C:/Users/Bakaiya/Documents/ogre/OgreMain/include"
)
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")

link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
add_executable(${Project_Name} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${Project_Name} SDL2main SDL2 OgreMain) #Ogre
```

Running the "generate makefile" command in the IDE completes without issue, but does not fix the problem. Additionally, clean fails, but "help" does work.

This is a problem within the IDE, it seems, because if I run make from the command line in the project root, it builds without issue.

*Also, I fiddled with the file path mode setting under C/C++ -> Project Options, and it did nothing. Even set to absolute, what seems to be a relative path (CMakeFiles/Makefile2) is still in the failed command. I'm not sure if that option is expected to change that sort of reference or not.*

What could be wrong with this imported project to cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I attempt to build the project, I get a rather cryptic (Java?) error message:

This is an error shown by netbeans to tell you, that it was unable to execute `make` command successfully. Usually this indicates a wrong setting of your (mingw-) tools.

Here are some points you can check:

1. Don't use `make` from `mingw/bin`, you have to use the one from `mingw/msys/..`. There's a mingw make within mingw's msys folder, usually `C:\<Path to MSYS>\<Version>\bin\make.exe` - this `bin`-path must also be set in **`PATH`** environment variable! If MSys wasn't installed with your mingw installation, please install it.
2. Please check the tools set in **`Tools -> Options -> C/C++ -> Build Tools`**; you can test them by clicking `Versions...`.
3. (If existing) Clean the CMake *generated* files and clean the cmake's cache. If not done yet, please use an out-of-source build as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608569/can-cmake-and-netbeans-play-nice/23443404#23443404).
4. Can you build your project from terminal (without netbeans)?

---

> The first directory (/C/MinGW/bin/make.exe) stands out to me as not being in Windows-format, but I am not sure if that's incorrect.

This is ok and intended by mingw - it uses linux / unix like paths.

---

## Update

> ### Which make program should I use?
>
> Many MinGW users have a problem because they use mingw32-make.exe from
>   the MinGW installation. While this seems like the right choice, it
>   actually breaks the build. The problem is that this is a non-Posix
>   implementation of the Unix make program and doesn't work well at all.
>   In fact, thats why the MinGW people renamed it! They've also made a
>   FAQ entry explaining why you should not use mingw32-make.exe. Instead,
>   you should use the make.exe program from the MSYS package.
>
> As of NetBeans 6.1, the Build Tools panel no longer allows a user to
>   select mingw32-make. If you choose a MinGW compiler collection it will
>   default to make in MSYS. If MSYS is not found, it will tell you no
>   make program has been found.

*(http://wiki.netbeans.org/MinGWInCCDevelopmentPack)*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Setting it to msys' make fixed the problem immediately. For future reference should this sort of thing happen again, is there some reason msys make is used over mingw make? I believe my last IDE used mingw's make, but I am not sure.

Comment: The default mingw `make` is a *non-POSIX* implementation (it's a Win32 Make!?) but the MSys one is. Since most of the time a posix compatible make is required, the first fails.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a good explanation from NB wiki; the page itself is about NB 5.x / 6.x but the answers are still valid.