# Managing Integration Tests in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, netbeans, integration-testing, cppunit

I'm using Netbeans for developing an enterprise project which has unit tests and integration tests. I'm using CPPUNIT for developing unit tests but I have a problem.
As you know unit test should be quick so I developed them small and I can run them by using IDE plugin every time I need. But integration test are some time consuming test which cannot be run time to time. So where should I store them?
If I put them into another project their management will become a nightmare. If I put them in current project I cannot tell the Netbeans that they should not be run in executing unit tests.
What is your idea about my problem?

Comment: My idea is to separate unit tests and integration tests.

Comment: I know that but the problem is how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the NB make build management (= default C++ project). It's very tricky with those; you my try using different configurations, but that's not perfect though.

My recommendation is **using a dedicated build tool** like [Cmake](https://cmake.org/), which is [**greatly supported by Netbeans**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608569/can-cmake-and-netbeans-play-nice). This will allow you a ***clear separation*** of Unit- and integration tests within one project.

So your project might look like this:

```
<project>
|
+-- src/
|
+-- include/
|
+-- test/ (unit tests)
|
+-- integration/ (integration tests)
|
…
```

You than can use **different make targets**; eg. `make unittest` or `make integrationtest`. It's also possible to disable each kind of test as you need them (so they wont compile / carry dependencies).

In the build settings you can even set, that the **unittests** should be **build and executed after each build** by default - while you run the **integration tests manually** whenever you need to.

Btw. the *project isn't bound to an IDE* from now on. You can develop using whatever tool you want to + *Continuous Integration server* can handle it too.