# NetBeans create a static Library c++

Tags: c++, netbeans, static, static-libraries

I have already a project in C++ and I want to create a static library for this project. I placed in the NetBeans my C++ project via Drag and drop.

Now, how can I create a static library for this project?

I have 8.2 version NetBeans in Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any project or build system configured yet, you can either create a netbeans project or a project based on a build tool like cmake or make. If you already have a running build system it's possible to use this from within NB.

### New Netbeans Project

First create a Netbeans Project for a static library:

1. New Project --> C/C++
2. C/C++ Static Library
3. Copy your source to the project or set the paths to your source

### Using a build system (eg. Cmake or Make)

This set applies to the case where you already have an existing build system or want to use one.

1. New Project --> C/C++
2. C/C++ Project with Existing Sources
3. Select the path of your source code and select what you need. Follow the wizard and you are done.

---

For using CMake you can get a detailed step to step guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23443404/1622894).